# NoMethodError: undefined method `from_json' for "{}":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I load up the Rails console in my project, I can do this:

```
{}.to_json
```

But I can't do this:

```
"{}".from_json
```

Even when I require the json gem first, it doesn't work. Does a `from_json` method even exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `from_json` does not exist. If you want to get a Ruby hash from a JSON string, you can use the `JSON#parse` method. Example below:

`json = JSON.parse("{\"hello\": \"world\"}")`

the above returns `{"hello"=>"world"}`

Answer (score 2):

Your `{}.to_json` assumption is correct.  However when we're taking JSON data (or any textual data for that matter) and converting it to some native structure we call that process parsing.  An instance method of a class that parsed some textual data and initialized its attributes with that data would be odd - a bit out of place.  Instead what you typically see are static factory methods (known as class methods in Ruby), like:

```
JSON.parse "{}"
```

This will return a hash in Ruby.

Comment: But from_json would be an instance method of String, not of Hash or Array, so it wouldn't initialize its own attributes but attributes of a Hash or Array. I don't see why that would be odd.

Comment: If you really want this functionality (maybe as part of a DSL or for convenience) you can extend `String` to add it.  The factory method approach, `JSON.parse`, is a typical pattern in software development which is why you see that instead of `String#from_json`.

Answer (score 0):

No, as mentiond below and above, a `.from_json` method does not exist. But its kinda simple to implement on you own:

```
require 'json'
class String
  def from_json
    JSON.load(self) rescue false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just happened across this. from_json is now in the framework.

From the docs...

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  attr_accessor :name, :age, :awesome

  def attributes=(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    instance_values
  end
end
```

I generally use it to serialize JSON to ActiveModel objects...

```
json.each do |object|
    object = object.to_json
    myModel = MyModel.new
    myModel.from_json(object)
end
```

The error reporting is kinda bad with the "from_json" method, if I was dealing with malformed JSON I would get the undefined method error.

Years later, HTH!